# Android Material BottomSheet disappears after expanding

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, bottom-sheet

### Requirement:

I am trying to implement the following [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiSdW.png). It will contain 4 parts:

> 1. Toolbar
> 2. View / Layout
> 3. FAB
> 4. BottomSheet (Initially hidden)

The requirement is simple. When FAB is clicked the FAB container (`binding.actionsContainer`) will hide and then, BottomSheet will animate to its `peekHeight`. And when close (x) button in the toolbar is clicked, BottomSheet will hide and FAB container will appear. But along with that I want to resize the middle part (View / Layout) with animation (ie: a responsive behavior).

### Done so far:

I used `ValueAnimator` in combination with `translationY` and `updateLayoutParams` to resize and hide the views.

```
override fun onFabButtonClicked(view: View) {
    val actionViewValueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, binding.actionsContainer.height)
    actionViewValueAnimator.duration = 400L
    actionViewValueAnimator.addUpdateListener {
        val animatedValue = actionViewValueAnimator.animatedValue as Int
        binding.actionsContainer.translationY = animatedValue.toFloat()

        val params = binding.canvas.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
        val verticalMargin = params.topMargin + params.bottomMargin

        var fixedHeight = binding.root.height
        fixedHeight -= binding.appbar.height
        fixedHeight -= binding.actionsContainer.height - animatedValue
        fixedHeight -= verticalMargin
        binding.canvas.updateLayoutParams { height = fixedHeight }
    }

    actionViewValueAnimator.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
            bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED

            val bottomSheetValueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(bottomSheetBehavior.peekHeight, 0)
            bottomSheetValueAnimator.duration = 400L
            bottomSheetValueAnimator.addUpdateListener {
                val animatedValue = bottomSheetValueAnimator.animatedValue as Int

                val params = binding.canvas.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
                val verticalMargin = params.topMargin + params.bottomMargin

                var fixedHeight = binding.root.height
                fixedHeight -= binding.appbar.height
                fixedHeight -= bottomSheetBehavior.peekHeight - animatedValue
                fixedHeight -= verticalMargin
                binding.canvas.updateLayoutParams { height = fixedHeight }
            }
            bottomSheetValueAnimator.start()
        }
    })
    actionViewValueAnimator.start()
}
```

### Issue:

When the 2nd animation (`bottomSheetValueAnimator`) starts, BottomSheet animates to it's peekHeight but right after that it dissapears! My guess is that the animation of BottomSheet somehow conflicting with my ValueAnimator. Is it really the case? And how can I resolve this issue?

### Preview:

Here is the [preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSOpE.gif) of the issue.

Comment: check the `fixedHeight` in your listener. maybe it come 0 after updating

Comment: No. I checked again just now, no issue there. Does it have nothing to do with the BottomSheet? As I used this variable only to update the View (part #2).